# How does one disable an option enabled by default in Kconfig?

Tags: linux-kernel

Let's say I have an option:

```
config SETTING_WITH_DEFAULT
    bool "Some setting which defaults to y"
    default y
```

I want to make an option which would deselect this default:

```
config PLATFORM_INCOMPATIBLE
    bool "This platform isn't compatible with above config"
    # What should I put here?
```

If I had `platform_incompatible_defconfig` and I would run `make` with this configuration I would like said option to be turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Figured that I can do it otherwise in my case: In my platform-specific config stub I can have, besides the `CONFIG_PLATFORM_INCOMPATIBLE=y` option also a `CONFIG_SETTING_WITH_DEFAULT=n` selection. I wonder if there is another way to do this though.